# Tapping background to close subview in Xcode 4.3

Tags: ios, ipad, user-interface, subview

Currently I am creating an app. for the ipad that uses a media player. When you click on a button the media player pops up and I have code that when you press another button the media player stops and is hidden so you can go back to using the superview. The problem is, I dont want to have to click a button to close the subview, I want to be able to click anywhere on the background to close. I've tried making the whole background a button but I'm having trouble writing code to make it so that the full window button that closes the subview ONLY appears when the subview is up. Right now the full window button is up constantly so I can't click on the button that brings up the subview in the first place because the large button is overlapping. I hope this dilemma is fairly easy to understand. If not I can send some code.

Answer (score 1):

Try a [UIPopover](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html) instead.  What you're describing is the default behavior.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and get back to you. As a novice programmer I may need more guidance but I'll see what I can do. Thank you for the help